# JBoss AS 7.1.1/EAP 6.1 app.war (file) vs app.war (folder)

Tags: java, deployment, jboss7.x, apache-camel

When a deploy my app.war (folder) this starts Apache Camel's routes, but when deploy app.war (file) not work Apache Camel's routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem overriding Camel's class that make Annotation scan.